# VS2012 LESS Comments' Background Color with Web Essentials

Tags: visual-studio-2012, comments, less, background-color, web-essentials

VS2012 Update 1, Web Essentials 2.6

With "Tools > Options" the background color of CSS comments is set to some non-white color. If coding a single line comment with "//", the characters of the comment are correctly colored. However, the comment's spaces still have a white background. This makes reading the comment difficult.

How can I set  the entire comment's background color correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We're aware of the issue with // comments in LESS and a fix is coming. It's not Web Essentials that causes this though.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Also with /**/ the background color is not correct.